# Android 13 notification content is empty after interacting with the notification buttons

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

When I run my app on Android 13, the notification content becomes empty after interacting with the buttons. I have implemented the change related to the permission for Android 13 devices. Basically I'm able to see only the app logo and an empty notification, for all the buttons I have PendingIntents which are sent when the user interacts with them. The notification is displayed for a foreground service.
Any help Ould be appreciated!